# Proving the convergence of the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(2^j)^2}{j!}$ without root or ratio test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am given the series: 
$\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(2^j)^2}{j!}$ and I can show that it converges by using the ratio test, but I'm not sure how to approach to prove its convergence without it.

Comment: Why do you want to prove convergence without the ratio test?

Comment: Solving through problems in a real analysis book and stuck on a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$a_j
=\frac{(2^j)^2}{j!}
$.
Then
$\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}
=\frac{\frac{(2^{j+1})^2}{(j+1)!}}{\frac{(2^j)^2}{j!}}
=\frac{2^{2(j+1)-2j}}{j+1}
=\frac{4}{j+1}
$.

Therefore,
for
$j \ge 9$,
$\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}
\le \frac12$.

By induction,
for
$j \ge 9$ and
$k \ge 1$,
$\frac{a_{j+k}}{a_j}
\le \frac1{2^k}
$.

Therefore
for
$j \ge 9$ and
$k \ge 1$,
$a_{j+k}
\le a_j\frac1{2^k}
$
so that,
for $j \le 9$,
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{j+k}
\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_j\frac1{2^k}
=a_j
$.

Since initial terms of a sum
do not affect the convergence,
the sum converges.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by explicit comparison with some nice series. For the sum from $8$ to $\infty$, note that the top is $4^j$ and the bottom is greater than $8^{j-7}$, that is, $8^{-7}8^j$. Thus for $j\ge 8$ we can compare with $8^7\sum_8^\infty \left(\frac{4}{8}\right)^j$.

*Remark*: This comparison is in principle not far from the Ratio Test, which fundamentally is also a comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: And for $n\ge9$, $\dfrac{4^n}{n!}<\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-9}$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: For no good reason, I decided to compare with the "canonical" geometric series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$. Lots of options.

Comment: I thought in order to compare, it had to be greater than all n, not just from 8 or 9?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I noticed that $a_n$ was first less than $1$ when $n=9$ and that $\dfrac{a_{10}}{a_9}=\frac{2}{5}$ and the rest was trivial.

Comment: @MathematicianInWorks   If it converges from $9$ onward, then it converges, since the sum of the first  eight terms is finite.

Comment: @MathematicianInWorks:  Not that it matters, but if $j\le 7$, then your $a_j$ is $\le 8^7 (1/2)^j$.  The $4^7$ could be replaced by something far smaller, but for proof of convergence there is need to do so.

Answer (score 2):

We have: $\dfrac{j^2}{j!}= \dfrac{j}{(j-1)!}= \dfrac{1}{(j-2)!}+ \dfrac{1}{(j-1)!}$, and you can reindex to show each of them converges, and they are easy to show to be convergent by comparing each with a $p>1$ -series.

If you have the series with $2^{2j} = 4^j$, then you would use $e^4$ as the targeting sum for the series. So either series is convergent hand down.

Comment: hey terribly sorry, I made a typo in my initial question. It was supposed to be 2^j, not 2*j

Answer (score 0):

If you know $\sum 1/j^2 < \infty,$ you can argue like this: For $j\ge 6,$

$$\frac{4^j}{j!} = \frac{4}{j}\frac{4}{j-1} \cdots \frac{4}{4}\frac{4}{3}\frac{4}{2}\frac{4}{1}\le  \frac {4^6}{4!}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}.$$

Dividing the term on the right by $1/j^2$ and letting $j\to \infty$ gives a finite limit. Thus the limit comparison test shows our series converges.

Comment: @zhw...any reason to divide it by $1/j^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming as known $\sum 1/j^2< \infty.$

Comment: $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{4^j}{j!}=$finite sum$+\sum_{6}^{\infty}\frac{4^j}{j!}$. Now the summation on RHS is less than or equal to $\sum_{6}^{\infty}\frac{4^6}{4!}\frac{1}{j(j-1)}$$\approx\sum_{6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}$.

Comment: And you know that because by dividing the terms of the first series by those of the second you have a sequence that has a finite positive limit.

Comment: @zhw...Is my comment not sufficient to prove the result? Where is the fallacy?

Comment: You asked me a question. I answered it. Then you wrote something that is exactly what I did, with one exception: I proved it. In other words how do you know the terms are $\approx$? You divide one by the other and take a limit.